# Java: split string into hashtable by delimiters

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

Running java in my cgi-bin. Via post request. In my java program, I have the browser output in a string e.g.: `name=josh&age=34`.... and so on

In my java program `String x = "name=joshua";`

How can I split this `x` string by the = delimiter into a hashtable.

My hashtable is `Hashtable<String, String>`

Comment: [how to split String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Duplicate of [Splitting URL query string to key-value pairs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175332/splitting-url-query-string-to-key-value-pairs)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Standard question nowadays, did you try something yourself? Please post any code you have and explain where you are stuck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
// initializes a hashtable for key and value types to be String
Hashtable<String, String> h = 
              new Hashtable<String, String>();
// your string
String x = "name=josh";
// splits the string for "=" delimiter and stores in an array
String[] arrOfStr = x.split("=", 0); 
// Use the 'put' method of Hashtable to insert the 0th element of array as key and 1st element as value
h.put(arrOfStr[0],arrOfStr[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks!! If my browser output string contains a bunch of info  (key=value) I can use a for loop to the length of the string array and keep putting key=value.. I appreciate it. I'm fairly new to java